Terraform Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated
I got this warning:
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated   
   
  on best.tf line 69, in locals:   
   69:   pools = length(var.instances) > 0 ? { "${var.name}" = var.instances } : { for p in var.pools: p.name => p.instances }   
   
Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be   
provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To   
silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"   
sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.   
   
Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from   
expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a   
mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only   
to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence. 

which makes sense. So I changed "${var.name}" to var.name and then I got this error:
Error: Ambiguous attribute key   
   
  on best.tf line 69, in locals:   
   69:   pools = length(var.instances) > 0 ? { var.name = var.instances } : { for p in var.pools: p.name => p.instances }   
   
If this expression is intended to be a reference, wrap it in parentheses. If   
it's instead intended as a literal name containing periods, wrap it in quotes   
to create a string literal.

Which made me say out loud: "Come on, Terraform!", which made my colleagues look at me funny.

What's the value of var.name?

Great question @RuiJarimba :) A string whose length is either 14 or 19 characters.

Does that 14 or 19 characters string contain non-alphanumeric characters?

Great question again @RuiJarimba! it contains only lower case English characters and hyphen-minus symbol: "-" whose ASCII code is 45.

Let's break it down to the smallest terraform sample code we can:
variable "a" { default = "aaa" }
variable "b" { default = "bbb" }

locals {
  pools = { var.a = var.b }
}

output "test" {
  value = local.pools
}

That will reproduce your error:
Error: Ambiguous attribute key
If this expression is intended to be a reference, wrap it in parentheses. If it's instead intended as a literal name containing periods, wrap it in quotes to create a string literal
We can not have a variable as a key like that...

just do what the error says wrap it in parentheses :
variable "a" { default = "aaa" }
variable "b" { default = "bbb" }

locals {
  pools = { (var.a) = var.b }
}

output "test" {
  value = local.pools
}

The terraform plan on that will be:
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = {
      + aaa = "bbb"
    }


another hack is to do it in a loop:
variable "a" { default = "aaa" }
variable "b" { default = "bbb" }

locals {
  pools = {for x in [1]: var.a => var.b }
}

output "test" {
  value = local.pools
}

and a terraform plan on that will be:
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = {
      + aaa = "bbb"
    }


I was thinking the error might have been caused by non-alphanumeric chars like dots (.). The loop hack is cool, I didn't know that was possible :-)

@RuiJarimba i did not test that give it a try see if it causes any issues
